# Troubleshoot fastboot error 'remote: ' command not defined

Tags: fastboot, bootloader, 8.1-oreo, bootloader-lock

> Device: iMX 7ULP evaluation kit
>
> Platform-tools: r28.0.3
>
> Image: O8.1.0_1.4.0_ANDROID_TOOL_7ULP_GA (ARM 32 Android 8.1)

I used the image provided by [nxp](https://www.nxp.com/support/developer-resources/evaluation-and-development-boards/i.mx-evaluation-and-development-boards/android-os-for-i.mx-applications-processors:IMXANDROID?tab=Design_Tools_Tab) website on the device. Then I tried unlocking it.

According to a [tutorial](https://www.theandroidsoul.com/unlock-bootloader-via-fastboot-android/), I used `adb` to bring the system in bootloader via

```
> ./adb reboot bootloader
```

The device goes to the splash screen and stop there (Not sure if that's how it should be). `adb` does not recognize the device anymore and `fastboot` fails on any command as fowllows

```
> ./fastboot.exe oem unlock
                                FAILED (remote: ' unlock device failed.')
fastboot: error: Command failed
```

```
> ./fastboot oem device-info
                                FAILED (remote: ' command not defined')
fastboot: error: Command failed
```

```
> ./fastboot flashing unlock
                                FAILED (remote: ' unlock device failed.')
fastboot: error: Command failed
```

How can I troubleshoot that and unlock the device?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem eventually.

In the `developer options`, there is an option `OEM unlocking` which must be allowed. Otherwise `fastboot` fails.